# passing in parameters in javascript properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

currenty i am hard coding in the url and the id into a function but i would like to pass them in so it is not specific to the hard coding.

**Code to pass in parameters -currently hard coded**

```
 Next = function () {
    var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
    $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(_page);
    $.views.Roster.GetPage("/api/Roster", 9, _page);
}
```

I wouldl ike to have the last line changed to: `$.views.Roster.GetPage(url, id, _page);`

**Current method with parameters passed in**

```
$.views.Roster.GetPage = function (url, id, pageNumber) {
        $.ajax({
            Url: url,
            DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I don't know anything about knockout, but is `$.ajax({})` a knockout method or a jQuery method?

Comment: $.ajax() is a jQuery method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald I know that, but I was confused because the other method calls were with $ as well, and I've never seen it (like $.views.Roster). I was also confused because none of the options used actually match watch what $.ajax accepts. So I thought maybe there was some Knockout AJAX method or something. And I wasn't sure if Knockout might have used the same identifier - $. jQuery isnt tagged in the question either

Comment: I understand. No problem man, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your function:

```
 Next = function (url, id) {
    var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
    $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(_page);
    $.views.Roster.GetPage(url, id, _page);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and in console i got `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation ` for `Next`.

Comment: Where are you calling `Next`?

Comment: `<li><a href="#" data-bind="click: Next">Next</a></li>`

Comment: And where do you want to define or get the values for url and id from?

Comment: from view page in script section: `(function ($) {
            $.views.Roster.GetPage('@url', @ViewBag.SectionID, 1);
           
        })(jQuery);`

Comment: Not entirely sure on this one (since I'm not sure about how databinding happens in knockout) but you could try this: `<li><a href="#" data-bind="click: Next" data-url="yoururl" data-id="yourid">Next</a></li>'` and in your function: `$.views.Roster.GetPage($(this).data("url"), $(this).data("id"), _page);`